# Is cracking software with server emulators illegal?

Tags: software, hacking

Let's say I have a program that needs you to login with a paid account in order to use it, and it sends authorization data to a server (username and pass) using this example link (I show example credentials): http://foo.bar/checkUser?user=PKTINOS&pass=password

In this sample, the authorization link returns "Success" if the credentials are valid and "Failure" if they are not.

And let's say I have another 3rd-party program that redirects that link to my own URL, e.g., http://bar.foo/checkUser, that happens to always return "Success."

(This would allow you to use the program with false credentials.)

Would that violate any law?

Comment: COUNTRY ????????

Comment: Side note: A well designed web application would still give you unauthorized errors if the login was not performed by the web application itself. (E.g., it would reject the token from your fake login because it doesn't have a record of generating it or it would reject the cookie because it wasn't encrypted with the right key.) If you know of a web site that does this, you may want to look into informing them of the vulnerability somehow. There are some questions on [Security.SE] that may be helpful in determining how to do this with minimal risk to yourself.

Comment: To be clear, you lawfully obtained the copy of the program, correct? You didn't steal it or violate any license to get it. Otherwise, of course, you're already sunk and your question isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Forget about copyright or EULAs. In the UK this would be illegal under the [Computer Misuse Act (1998)](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18) and **you could be jailed for up to a year** - specifically

> Unauthorised access to computer material.
>
> (1)A person is guilty of an offence if—
>
> (a)he causes a computer to perform any function with intent to secure access to any program or data held in any computer, or to enable any such access to be secured;
>
> (b)the access he intends to secure, or to enable to be secured, is unauthorised; and
>
> (c)he knows at the time when he causes the computer to perform the function that that is the case.

This law has been applied even to simply altering parameters in a GET request to a website, so it is incredibly broad.

Other jurisdictions have similar wording, so be aware!

Comment: It's not clear the owner and possessor of the computer that the program is held in isn't entitled to determine whether the access is authorized.

Comment: It can only be unauthorised if you don't have an account though, right? If you do have an account, you may still for whatever reason prefer to play on a private server, but that's when other laws come into play.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: (c) actually spells out explicitly that lack of knowledge is a defence. All three conditions (a)-(c) must be met simultaneously in order for an offence to have occurred.

Comment: I meant it doesn't matter that the owner of the service doesn't know what the cracker is doing - I think that is what Ross was saying

Comment: Assuming he lawfully possesses both the computer and the program, in what sense is the access unauthorized?

Comment: David - the server is not his, as I understand it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop And he's asking about a case where he does *not* access that server.

Answer (score 2):

As a first note, I will provide the obvious statement that this may vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction and I speak only from knowledge of UK law and the resources at my disposal that may cover some other jurisdictions in a light touch manner.

As your question considers the scenario where you are spoofing a check for a paid account, I will assume that you do not possess the appropriate license for the software and are using this technique to circumvent what is a license verification procedure.

That said, usually this would be illegal as you are using a piece of software without the appropriate license. This follows the agreement (read contract) you have formed in the installation of the program - the EULA (end user license agreement). Where the EULA stipulates that you only have rights to utilise the software if you have the appropriate license, you would still be in breach. See section 1.g. of the [McAfee EULA](http://www.mcafee.com/us/resources/legal/end-user-license-agreements-en-gb.pdf).

Furthermore, while you may not be in *direct* breach of the decompilation/modification restrictions imposed by the [EULA (3.f.)](http://www.mcafee.com/us/resources/legal/end-user-license-agreements-en-gb.pdf), you may still be in breach of the proscription of 'Reverse Engineering', as through your analysis of the software you have been able to exploit a particular aspect.

Obviously, I have opted to use a fairly comprehensive EULA for the purpose of this answer and it is feasible that there may be software produced without the relevant provisions and protections.

Comment: Of course, jurisdictions that specifically authorize Reverse Engineering as a matter of law (e.g. Netherlands) are different.

Comment: @MSalters I completely agree - though other provisions of EULA may still proscribe the result of the Reverse Engineering.

Comment: I don't think so. The law trumps any EULA restrictions on Reverse Engineering; those provisions are null and void.

Comment: Breach of contract is not generally a crime in the UK.

Comment: You're assuming that the person doing this is the same person who installed the program.

Comment: @MSalters I don't mean any restrictions on Reverse Engineering in the EULA, just that the act enabled/discovered by the reverse engineering would still be in breach of other provisions, if that makes more sense?

Comment: @bdsl whilst not a crime, breach of contract is still, for the intent/purpose of this question, able to be brought before the courts and the party in breach subject to a court order, point taken though.

Comment: @David You are correct, though it is interesting to note that example I provided also proscribes 'allowing third parties' to break certain terms, and as such the installer would then be liable.

Comment: I think there's a big difference between criminal and civil law. It also isn't clear that there is any contract - what consideration is the user supposed to provide?

Comment: @bdsl should the user also be the installer, then they will have accepted the license terms when installing, but as pointed out above, this begins to unravel if the user did not install the software.

Comment: Simply accepting terms doesn't form a contract - for an agreement to be a contract two parties have to agree to each do something for the benefit of the other (e.g. paying money and supplying goods).

Comment: @bdsl Consideration can be found in the benefit to the installer in the use of the software and the software producers has the benefit of having specific rights protected.

Comment: @MorganHickman I don't think that works in the United States. In the United States, a person who lawfully possesses a work already has the right to perform any step necessary to using the work in the ordinary way. I don't see how there's any consideration in someone granting you permission to do something you already had the legal right to do. (Absent a law specifying otherwise, you have the right to do whatever you want with anything you lawfully possess. 17 USC 106 does not remove this right, nor does any other law.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't profess to have the requisite understanding of US Law to answer in that context, but I have edited to clarify my assumption (due to lack of information in the question) that the individual concerned has not lawfully obtained the work (as if they had, why would they need to crack/'spoof' a server-side license verification).

Comment: @MorganHickman "*if they had, why would they need to crack/'spoof' a server-side license verification*" It's not at all uncommon for someone to have a lawful copy of a work but not have the ability to use it in some particular way. For example, anyone can lawfully acquire a copy of pretty much any version of Windows, that won't let you activate it. Or you can lawfully acquire a DVD with several versions of a program, (all of which you've lawfully obtained) but only have a license to use one particular version. You can download trial versions of programs, and thus lawfully possess copies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz as I understand it, you are blurring the line between the ownership of a work and permitted use of a work. In very few circumstances does the possession of a CDROM (or similar medium) constitute ownership of the software that is loaded on it - it remains the intellectual property of the software publisher and as such you are only permitted to use it if you are licensed to do so and are obligated to adhere to the license terms.

Comment: @MorganHickman That's a common misconception. If I lawfully possess a DVD of The Phantom Menace, I have the legal right to the ordinary use of that work. That doesn't change the fact that it's the intellectual property of Disney. It's just that intellectual property is a bundle of specific rights (see 17 USC 106) and that does not include the right to control the work's ordinary use by those who lawfully possess it. (It does include the right to distribute it to the public, so I can't do that without a license.) When you buy a book, you have the right to read it -- you do not need a license.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52291/discussion-between-morgan-hickman-and-david-schwartz).